SQLAlchemy w/ Flask - Smart/safe to expunge_all() on request?
I have a Flask web app, using Flask-SQLAlchemy.For the most part, it just does database reads and serves content to users.
The database is defined on the app module like this:
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config=Config, constants=Constants):
    ...

Getting to my question...
Sometimes, a user request will trigger a commit().
Also sometimes, the app's view functions modify an in-session instance to a value that should not be persisted to the database.
So, if the user's next action is one that triggers a commit(), this will issue an UPDATE of that instance.
Thus, should I expunge_all() after all requests, to make sure this doesn't happen?
(Or, possibly: Does SQLAlchemy preclude the need for this? Can I be guaranteed that each request is a separate database session?)

Normally each request is a separate session. Not clear what you are doing. Also a bit strange to be being updating data that you don't really want updated ... what is going on? Note here is the basics: basics-of-using-a-session
